Chess Drawn Proof Game No. 2
Here's another puzzle where the game is defined to end in a draw. The German PDB database doesn't seem to include the solution yet, so as of today, it's safe to show the link to this puzzle (A.Buchanan, 2023) I think it's a little harder than the previous one.
Question: what’s the entire proof game leading to this position, where White's 14th move has just drawn the game?

This problem was used in the annual French RIFACE Chess Retro Solving Competition in 2023. You may come to a point where you think that the solution is not quite unique. If so, you are on the right track, but you are missing a trick or two.
(As mentioned before: in formal chess problems under the Codex, there are 4  ways of drawing a game. Firstly, the rules for stalemate and draw by repetition are always in force. Moreover, in "retros" (such as this problem), the fifty move & dead position rules also apply. There's no claiming involved: if at any point, the game criteria are satisfied, the game is over. These default settings can always be over-ridden if necessary by specifying in the problem stipulation.)
Have fun! :)

There's a red dot on A7

I believe I have found the answer, but at the moment cannot completely justify why it is necessarily unique. The game went like this:

 1. Na3 Nc6 2. Nc4 Ne5 3. Nxe5 h5 4. Nxf7 Nh6 5. Nxh6 a6 6. Ng4 hxg4 7. f4 Rxh2 8. Nf3 Rxh1 9. Nh2 Rg1 10. a3 Rh1 11. Nf3 Rg1 12. Nh2 Rh1 13. Nf3 Rg1 14. Nh2 draw

How can we go about finding this? Well, as in the last puzzle of this type, the draw necessarily had to be by repetition, which means that we must have visited this exact board position already after White's 10th move or even sooner. As such, we must first and foremost find a way to reach this position within 10 white and 9 black moves.
This is not so straightforward. Not a lot of these moves are readily apparent yet - we have only five visible black moves and only four from White. But these visible moves leave open a lot of questions, most notably the disappearance of the three knights, but also the fate of two pawns and the white rook. Both Ph2 and Rh1 conveniently lie on the path of the black rook (at the small cost of an extra move by black), so it seems natural to assume that the remaining white knight must be the piece taken by Pg4. (This assumption turned out to be correct, but I have as of yet no argument why it could not have happened any other way.)
In order to reach g4, the white knight must have had to go on a journey over the board, which then gets much closer to the alloted number of 10 moves. As such, there remain very few possible other moves that White could have spent to capture the missing black pawn and knights. Given the assumption that the Rg1 captured White's h pawn, Black has only three remaining moves to get the pawn and knights to convenient squares for capture. And indeed, it turns out that there is exactly a single way to achieve this - the White knight from b1 marches through a3 and c4, eats bNe5 on the way to bPf and captures the other black knight on the way out on h6 before landing on g4, ready to be fed to bPh the next turn.
This maneuver takes exactly six moves and therefore cannot be delayed or altered as Black has only three more moves available, each with the rook who's path has only now become free.
It is at this point that some apparent flexibility sets in: Even though Black's moves are exactly determined, why should the order between White's a3, f5, Nf3, Nh2 matter all that much? At first glance, there seem to be three equally viable lines, namely


Nf3 Rxh2 8. a3 Rxh1 9. Nh2 Rg1 10. f4,




a3 Rxh2 8. f4 Rxh1 9. Nf3 Rg1 10. Nh2


and


f4 Rxh2 8. Nf3 Rxh1 9. Nh2 Rg1 10. a3.


What makes the last one different from the other two? The reasons are most delightful: The first one may look like the final position at a glance, but there is in fact a crucial difference - Black can capture en passant! Since this right expires on the next turn, the final position is not yet reached.
And the second one? Well, this position is indeed identical to the board state, BUT it is not the first position that would be repeated three times! As such, if play continued on that path, the game would necessarily have ended as a draw after Black's 13th move with no chance to play the final White move.
Hence, only the last option is possible, which finishes the task as shown at the start.
I found this puzzle considerably more challenging than the last one, but it was still a lot of fun figuring it out - especially seeing why these small variations are all impossible.

Well done indeed for persevering through the complexity and the tricks at the end. Your solution is completely correct. When I solved it manually, I asked what happens before and after hxg4. The piece captured there is no longer available for capturing duty, and Black has at least 3 subsequent rook moves so White must find at least 4 moves
